# (processing) why is `curveVertex` skipping points?

Tags: processing, curve

I'm using processing 3.5.3 and I'm drawing curves using `beginShape`, `curveVertex`, `endShape`. My window is 1200 pixels wide, and I'm plotting a sequence of points with evenly spaced x values. The space between x values is 1200/2000, less than a pixel. I know, this is a gross misuse of `curveVertex`, but it works. Each frame is taking a solid ten seconds to render (because of the math I'm using, not because of processing) and I'm saving each frame as a `.png`.

The problem is I'm getting these straight patches where there should be curves. It looks like big stretches of x values are getting skipped. I know it's multiple vertices getting skipped because the straight patches span multiple x pixels, maybe fifty-ish at worst. Most frames are fine but then there'll be one frame with huge patches missing. Any idea what could cause this?

Edit: here's the code and some frames showing the problem. The most relevant section is in `draw()`.

```
float r; // parameter for recurence
float dr; // change in r per frame
int lod = 2000; // level of detail for curves
int k; // recurrence depth
float yscale = 16; // scale down the y-axis by this factor

// transforms from [0, 1] to screen coordinates
void vertex(float x, float y) {
  curveVertex(x * width, (1 - y) * height);
}

void setup() {
  size(1200, 800);
  background(0);
  stroke(255);
  noFill();
  r = 3.7;
  k = 30;
  dr = 0.0005;
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  
  // animate r
  r += dr;
  if (r >= 4) {
    exit();
  }
  
  // draw the pdf of Xk
  stroke(255);
  beginShape();
  vertex(0, fn(0, k) / yscale);
  for (int i = 0; i <= lod; i++) {
    float x = i / (float)lod;
    vertex(x, fn(x, k) / yscale);
  }
  vertex(1, fn(1, k) / yscale);
  endShape();
  
  textSize(24);
  text(String.format("r = %.4f", r), 24, 24);
  
  saveFrame("output/frame_#####.png");
}

// pdf of Xn+1 = r*Xn*(1-Xn), where X0 is uniform
float fn(float x, int n) {
  if (n == 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  else if (x > r/4) {
    return 0;
  }
  else {
    float d = sqrt(1 - 4/r*x);
    return (fn(0.5 + 0.5*d, n-1) + fn(0.5 - 0.5*d, n-1)) / (r*d);
  }
}
```

And here's a particularly bad frame:
[image: A bad frame]

Comment: Post code and image output.

Comment: @micycle posted, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I transformed your code to render into a PShape and then iterated over the vertices of the PShape to determine whether the vertices themselves are present (and are not being joined up), or whether they are missing completely:

[image]
Vertices in green -- they are missing during the sections.

`curveVertex()` within a PShape works in `P2D` renderer mode only. Interestingly, in this mode (in contrast to default `JAVA2D` renderer) the previously straight sections are not present...

...which lead me to look at the values given to the vertices: I tried constraining them to the dimensions of the screen:

by changing this:

`curveVertex(x * width, (1 - y) * height);`

into this:

`curveVertex(constrain(x * width, 0, width), constrain((1 - y) * height, 0, height));`

And now we begin to understand what was happening:

**Constrained @ r = 3.7055:**
[image]

**Unconstrained @ r = 3.7055:**
[image]

**Verdict**

The equation was giving incredibly large values for certain coordinate points and Processing, or the curve algorithm itself, was skipping them. Once the values are constrained to a more reasonable level, the straight sections disappear and every point is joined up.

Comment: Thanks, I feel a little stupid now I should have been able to figure that out. Thank you for putting all that work in.